# Authentication from different table?

Tags: c#, authentication

I am new to mvc4 and trying to develop a new application where I have three user in table Employee, admin and customer. The problem  is that customer has many fields than employee or admin so I cannot make a single user table and then I made a different table for each user where username and password is included. Now I am lost when I want to authenticate user from their respective table. Is it possible or should I make user table separately with username and password? But doing so should I have to first create user every time before I create customer, employee and admin?

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: Sounds like [role-based authorization](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs) you want here.

Comment: That sounds like a really bad database setup.  You want everyone to be a user, then give them roles

Comment: Wouldn't that be a question for this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so i cannot make a single user table

Sure you can.  Just separate the "users" from the "details about the users."  For example, say you have a `Users` table here:

```
Users
---------
ID (PK)
Username
Password
(maybe a few other fields)
```

Then you san sub-type some other tables off of this one.  Tables like:

```
Employee
----------
ID (PK, FK to Users)
Name
EmployeeNumber
etc.

Customer
----------
ID (PK, FK to Users)
Name
CustomerNumber
etc.

Admin
----------
ID (PK, FK to Users)
(you get the idea)
```

Very similar to sub-classing in an object-oriented system, this allows you to sub-table in a relational system.  The login components in the application are only concerned with the `Users` table, then once authenticated the other components can get information about the user from the other tables.  (This has the added benefit of allowing a single user to be more than one thing.  Such as an `Employee` who is also an `Admin`.)

**Edit:** Keep in mind this is based on knowing *very* little about your relational data needs.  You might also be able to accomplish the same thing using a setup like:

```
Users
----------
ID (PK)
Username
etc.

Roles
----------
ID (PK)
RoleName

UsersInRoles
----------
UserID (FK to Users)
RoleID (FK to Roles)

(Other tables about users)
```

This setup is a lot closer to what's built in to the ASP.NET membership system as well, so you may be able to benefit significantly from it.  Though based on your description of your user data you may still need to sub-type some tables containing the user information in order to avoid having lots of null values.

Comment: I implemented as you said at the very beginning and it worked. Also I figure out that in mvc4 simple membership provider was inbuilt for user and role issue but I find it more difficult to implement for my case but your solution fit perfect on my case where i am using my own costume authentication.Thanks